# How can i set my own form view to enter customer data into res.partner model in odoo

Tags: odoo

How can I set my own form view to enter customer data into `res.partner` model without using `base.view_partner_form` form view of `res_partner` model?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will need the custom form view, of course.

And after that it depends, what you want to do.

Change the form view everywhere: Give your form view a lesser `priority` than "base.view_partner_form":

```xml
<record id="my_partner_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">...</field>
    <!-- other fields -->
    <field name="priority">1</field>
    <!-- arch -->
</record>
```

Or if you want to get a new menuitem for the users, just create one. Then create a `ir.actions.act_window` with your new form view as default view and link it to your new menuitem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new partner form and set priority.

By default system will load minimum priority form in odoo.

View default priority is 16 & if you give your view priority is 20 then default from view will be load.

Ex:

```
    <record id="view_partner_title_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.title.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner.title</field>
        <field name="priority">20</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Partner Titles">
                <group col="4">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="shortcut"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Now your new form view priority is 20, so system will load default form view because default form view priority is 16.

You can create **ir.actions.act_window.view**

Based on that system will load any sequence form/tree view based on your requirement.

```
    <record id="action_portal_partner_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Customers</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="domain">[('customer','=',True)]</field> 
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{"search_default_customer":1}</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="base.view_res_partner_filter"/>
    </record>

  <record id="action_portal_form_view2" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
      <field eval="23" name="sequence"/>
      <field name="view_mode">form</field>
      <field name="view_id" ref="view_partner_title_form"/>
      <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_portal_partner_form"/>
  </record>
```

**View_mode** : tree/form/..

**View Id**   : your view id

**Action**    : You must write correct action id